# Trying to XAMPP on Ubuntu 14.04

Tags: xampp

I install XAMPP and installation is successful but I am not able to start XAMPP. I get the following message:

```
Starting XAMPP for Linux 5.6.14-0...
XAMPP: Starting Apache...fail.
XAMPP:  Another web server is already running.
XAMPP: Starting MySQL...ok.
XAMPP: Starting ProFTPD...fail.
XAMPP:  Another FTP daemon is already running.
```

Comment: Why would you need to start xamp if it is already running?

Comment: The problem is that XAMPP wont start since "Another web server is already running" . Exactly the same question by Jan lies unanwered. See http://askubuntu.com/q/724921/507407

Answer (score 0):

From line 3 >>>

XAMPP:  Another web server is already running.

I Think. This mean the apache is already running.

PS. Sorry for my ugly english.

Answer (score 0):

What happens if you try to access http://localhost in your browser? It's likely that another webserver is already running.

On top of that, `lsof` and `netstat`  can give good visibility into what process is listening on what port.  All sorts of programs sometimes bind to ports.

```
lsof -i :80
```

or

```
sudo netstat -peanut | grep ":80"
```